# PayPal API Error -- This payment request must be authorized by the sender

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments, chained

In the delayed  chained adaptive Paypal the primary pay is successfully sent when i execute a payment with the pay key it shows an error like this

How could i authorize to send amount to secondary from primary  receiver

```
PayPal API Error

responseEnvelope.timestamp: 2012-10-31T01:12:05.386-07:00
responseEnvelope.ack:   Failure
responseEnvelope.correlationId: fd2c71e75c133
responseEnvelope.build: 3988550
error(0).errorId:   550001
error(0).domain:    PLATFORM
error(0).subdomain: Application
error(0).severity:  Error
error(0).category:  Application
error(0).message:   This payment request must be authorized by the sender
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this error, when I was trying to execute payment, that user had not payed yet, i.e. you make a pay request, then receive a pay key, then using this pay key user must follow url and pay (money will go to primary receiver), and after all you should execute payment to transfer money to secondary receivers.

Url I used in sandbox for user to pay:

```
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr&cmd=_ap-payment&paykey={{pay_key}},
```

where `{{pay_key}}` is a key from pay request.